# Django Restframework - Multiple models for SearchFilter

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Using Django 3.2 with Restframework.
Iam trying for search filter and create a API with restframework which would output the searched term with its whole object.

I had a little success on that with [official doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter). But from that I can only search in a single Model and not as globally.

Is there any existing document, blog on how to use multiple Models together? Or any working example.

As suggested by @Prince, for the [blog](https://yeti.co/blog/global-search-in-django-rest-framework/), I tried for following.

views.py

```
class GlobalSearchList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GlobalSearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
      query = self.request.query_params.get('query', None)
      users = MasterUser.objects.filter(Q(firstname__icontains=query) | Q(lastname__icontains=query) | Q(email__icontains=query) | Q(category__icontains=query))
      webinar = MasterWebinar.objects.filter(Q(host__icontains=query) | Q(title__icontains=query))
      resource = MasterResource.objects.filter(Q(route_name__icontains=query))
      section = ResourceSection.objects.filter(Q(resource_name__icontains=query))
      item = SectionItem.objects.filter(Q(item_title__icontains=query))
      all_results = list(chain(users,webinar, resource,section,item)) 
      return all_results
```

serializers.py

```
class GlobalSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = MasterUser
        fields = "__all__"
    def to_native(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, MasterIndividualMembers): 
            serializer = MasterIndividualMembersSerializer(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, MasterUser):
            serializer = MasterUserSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, MasterWebinar):
             serializer = MasterWebinarSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, MasterResource):
             serializer = MasterResourceSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, ResourceSection):
             serializer = ResourceSectionSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, SectionItem):
             serializer = SectionItemSerializer(obj)

        else:
            raise Exception("Not found in any instance!")
        return serializer.data
```

Here I stuck at `meta` class, since it accepts only 1 model.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this tutorial might it help you...

```
https://yeti.co/blog/global-search-in-django-rest-framework/
```

Comment: Does look helpful. I will implement and be back with updates.

Comment: I tried but it looks like, it needs a little update. The serializer's meta class only accepts only 1 model. I cant find a way to accept multiple models at a time. Any suggestions?